# Neovim LSP: language servers not found

Tags: typescript, neovim, pyright, tsserver

I'm trying to set up neovim's new LSP.

Following the manual I downloaded the plugin lspconfig, the pyright and typescript language servers, and sourced the setups in my `init.vim`, like so:

```lua
local nvim_lsp = require('lspconfig')

nvim_lsp.pyright.setup{}
nvim_lsp.tsserver.setup{}
```

Upon opening a `.py` or `.ts` file in a valid root_dir (having a package.json and/or setup.cfg, ...) I get no code errors, no intellisense, and `:LspInfo` shows 0 clients attached.

Now here's the catch: I installed language servers using `yarn global`, not `npm -g` and I'm using the asdf version manager, so their binaries may not be in the expected paths.

Does the LSP search for servers in predefined paths? If so how can I add to these paths?

Comment: Just looking quickly at the `nvim-lspconfig` [README's Debugging Section](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#debugging) it looks like there are a handful of other things to try after `:LspInfo`. Would it be possible to update your post with the output of the log file running with log level `debug`?